# Open/Close Animated Hamburger Menu when Clicking Button

Tags: javascript, css-animations, hamburger-menu

I'm using an animated hamburger menu (https://jonsuh.com/hamburgers/) to open a full screen menu.  It's all working as expected, **but** I can't figure out how to have the menu close on click (and of course reverse the animation).

I was able to add the class 'is-active' using JS, and adding "onclick="openNav()" works fine, but it seems like creating onclick="toggleNav()" might be more appropriate, I just can't seem to figure out how to write that in JS.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("popUpNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("popUpNav").style.height = "0%";
}

// Hamburger Menu Spin
var hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
hamburger.addEventListener("click", function() {

  hamburger.classList.toggle("is-active");

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hamburgers/0.9.3/hamburgers.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Full Screen Navigation -->
  <div id="primaryNav"> 
    <nav>
      <!-- Spinning Hamburger Button --> 
      <button class="hamburger hamburger--spin" type="button"   aria-label="Menu" aria-controls="navigation" aria-expanded="false" onclick="openNav()">
        <span class="hamburger-box">
          <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
      </button>

      <div id="popUpNav" class="overlay" onclick="closeNav()">

        <div class="overlay-content">
          <a href="#problemSolution" data-scroll onclick="closeNav()">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#" data-scroll onclick="closeNav()">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#" data-scroll onclick="closeNav()">Link 3</a>
          <a href="#" data-scroll onclick="closeNav()">Link 4</a>
        </div>          
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div><!--  End Primary Nav -->
```

Answer (score 3):

What I did:

Whenever the hamburger is being clicked, then we're going to check if it's already have `is-active` class. If it does, then it means the menu is currently active, and we should call `closeNav` in this scenario. If it doesn't have `is-active` class, then it means we should call `openNav`.

`closeNav` and `openNav` will:

- Add/Remove the class `is-active` from the hamburger.
- Add/Remove the style of the menu.

PS:

- Since you didn't provide your whole code, then we couldn't realy see if the current menu is `0% height` or `100% height`. so I changed it to `display block/none` only to show you that it works.
- I removed the `onclick` attribute from the `menu`, since you already have an EventListener for it.
- Make sure you don't include the `link` I provided in the example.

```js
function openNav() {
  hamburger.classList.add("is-active");
  document.getElementById("popUpNav").style.display = "block";
}

function closeNav() {
  hamburger.classList.remove("is-active");
  document.getElementById("popUpNav").style.display = "none";
}

// Hamburger Menu Spin
var hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");

hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => hamburger.classList.contains('is-active') ? closeNav() : openNav());

closeNav();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hamburgers/0.9.3/hamburgers.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Full Screen Navigation -->
<div id="primaryNav">
  <nav>
    <!-- Spinning Hamburger Button -->
    <button class="hamburger hamburger--spin" type="button" aria-label="Menu" aria-controls="navigation"
            aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="hamburger-box">
          <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
    </button>

    <div id="popUpNav" class="overlay" onclick="closeNav()">

      <div class="overlay-content">
        <a href="#problemSolution" data-scroll onclick="closeNav()">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#" data-scroll onclick="closeNav()">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#" data-scroll onclick="closeNav()">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#" data-scroll onclick="closeNav()">Link 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div><!--  End Primary Nav -->
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  I did in fact have a couple conflicting elements in my CSS that I had to clean up. I definitely was overcomplicating things. Thank you SO much!